# Avoid System.FormatException with Binding.Parse

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I have a `TextBox` which is bound to a property of type `decimal`. As I want the value in the textfield to be shown with two decimal points (e.g. 3.15), I have implemted the binding as follows:

```
Binding bindDecimal = new Binding("Text", viewModel, "myDecimal");
bindDecimal.Format += FormatDecimal;
bindDecimal.Parse += ParseDecimal;
```

The `.Format` function, so the interesting part is the `.Parse` function, which is implemented like this:

```
private void ParseDecimal(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType != typeof(decimal)) return;

    e.Value = Decimal.Parse(e.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Number);
}
```

Which works, as long as the value is a legit one. If I start using letters or (more realistically) just leave the field empty, it returns a *System.FormatException*, since it cannot convert the value to a decimal. A twist on the problem is, that it also occurs if you close the form window, while the `TextBox` is empty.

> **What is the best way to avoid this exception?**

Also, if it makes any difference, here is the `.Format` function:

```
private void FormatDecimal(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // The method converts only to string type. Test this using the DesiredType.
    if (e.DesiredType != typeof(string)) return;

    // Formats the value with two decimals
    e.Value = string.Format("{0:n2}", e.Value);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Decimal.TryParse? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have heard of that. However, I can't quite figure out how it would behave in a convert function...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void ParseDecimal(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType != typeof(decimal)) return;

    Decimal bob;

    if (Decimal.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out bob);
    {
        e.Value = bob;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `decimal.TryParse()`:

```
private void ParseDecimal(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType != typeof(decimal)) return;

    Decimal bob;

    Decimal.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out bob)

    // set e.Value to bob regardless of whether a true of false is returned
    // if true bob holds the parsed value.
    // if false bob holds the default value for decimal (zero), which you probably want to use
    e.Value = bob;

 }
```

Comment: Should I set `e.value` to some default value if `.TryParse` returns false? Or should I just leave un-touched then?

Comment: I updated the answer based on mjwills answer with explanation as to whether to use a default value or not.